# Missing dart:core lib Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a problem in my flutter project:

```
error: Required library 'dart: core' is missing. (missing_dart_library at [first_flutter_app] lib\main.dart:1)
```

and the dart lib is installed.
please help

Comment: Sounds like your Flutter installation is corrupted. Weird is the space between `'dart: core'`. I'd suggest you try to repair it following https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted

Comment: Works! thanks! @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Hmm, so I break it when I `git pull` the repository, probably because I didn't close the IDE nor stop the debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Run The Command "**flutter run**"

it will automatic download required tools and run your app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've upgraded you're flutter to new version.

type "**flutter run**" on you're terminal and hit enter it will automatically download required files and when download will finish it will automatically launch you're app to targeted device.

you can follow this article https://medium.com/fnplus/setting-up-flutter-for-windows-ca2c5e643fdf if you don't know how to set environment variable path.